# How to dynamically change the value of html Id inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of a product id from a hidden html input so i can use it in a JavaScript function

The Html code that i use to show product with their attributes

```
{% for produit in produits %}
        <li class="first product has-post-thumbnail">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{{asset('public/images/'~produit.getImage())}}" 
                     class="attachment-shop_catalog" 
                     alt="The Zoomer Robot Dog Toy   1"/>
                <h3>{{ produit.getNom() }} {{ produit.id }}</h3>
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="amount">{{produit.getPrix() }}</span>
                </span>
                <input id='inpt".{{ produit.id }}."' type="hidden" value="{{ produit.id }}">
            </a>
            <a  rel="nofollow" id="slim" class="button 
                add_to_cart_button product_type_simple" 
                onclick="ajouter()">Add to cart</a>
        </li>
```

the JavaScript Function to add in the cart shopping dynamically

```
<script>
    var ajouter = (function() {
        var executed = false;
        return function() {
            if (!executed) {
                executed = true;
                var
                    input = document.getElementById('inpt7').value;

                var urlEdit = "{{ 
                path('ajouterAuPanier', {
                    'id': "id"
                })
            }
        }
        ";

        urlEdit = urlEdit.replace("id", input);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlEdit,
            ifModified: true,
            success: function() {

                //document.getElementById('spam').innerText = "+1";                                                                  
                console.log("ggg");
                alert("ff");
            }
        });
        // 
        setTimeout(check_demande, 5000);
    }
    };
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Please, can you take the time to format your code?

Comment: Where is this hidden input? This code needs proper indentation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Firstly be sure to remove the additional quotation marks in your hidden field id so that it looks exactly like this

```
    <input id='inpt{{ produit.id }}' type="hidden" value="{{ produit.id }}">
```

Make sure you run the script to read the value from the field after the {{ }} expression is evaluated. If necessary place the script tag at the bottom of the **same html page**. Make sure that you write it this way to read the value using *eval()* javascript function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = document.getElementById('inpt{{produit.id}}');
        console.log(eval(x.value));
    </script>
```

You will have to write the same expression when refering to an html element id.
Hope this solves your problem. Thanks !